# How to add a new font in tinymce editor?

Tags: fonts, tinymce, font-face

I want to `add new font` in `tinymce editor` which are display in `font dropdown` and apply to editor text.

I try to add ttf font in fonts folder of advance themes skin folder and also add in `editor_template.js` and add css in `contect.css` for @font-face.

I got font name in fonts dropdown. But when i apply to any text no any font effect on that text.

What is actual problem i can't found. Hope this is path issue or other...

Answer (score 7):

I solved the issue,

Check all the possible issues below and fix them to add a font in TinyMCE editor.

- Create fonts folder : `tinymce/themes/advanced/`  - if not exists.

  1. Put font in fonts `"tinymce/themes/advanced/fonts/aphrodite_pro.ttf.`
  2. Add font in `editor_template.js & editor_template_src.js` include in `"theme_advanced_fonts"`

     `Ex: theme_advanced_fonts: "Aphrodite Pro=aphrodite pro"`,
- Maintain `"theme_advanced_fonts"` font name sequence in above both js files.

Most important part: `"Aphrodite Pro"` name is defined by us where `"aphrodite pro"` is the name of the font.

**Note** this might not work in TinyMCE version 4 or higher. Check new documentation: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#font_formats

Comment: Should font name same as ttf file name?

Comment: For TinyMCE version 4 or higher, see updated documentation here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#font_formats

Comment: where located this file editor_template.js & editor_template_src.js?

Answer (score 6):

Using Google Fonts i've just achieve this issue using two lines (in TinyMCE initialization):

```
content_css: ['https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi'],
font_formats: 'Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Gugi=Gugi, cursive;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;',
```

The new font is called Gugi and will appear between arial black and times new roman

Comment: For TinyMCE version 4 or higher, this is the correct answer. See documentation on it here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#font_formats

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [theme_advanced_fonts](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_fonts) configuration parameter according to your needs.
In case you need to add the font to the editor iframe head `contect.css` with `@font-face` is the right way.

Comment: I already add theme_advanced_fonts in configuration and @font-face in content.css but where to font ttf puts.. means in which folder (location of folder)?

Comment: I solved my issue...font name spacing issue... "aphrodite pro=aphrodite_pro" Change to =>  "Aphrodite Pro=aphrodite pro". Don't put underscore even in your font name have a underscore. Replace it with a space in "editor_template.js" file. Let me know if do not understand

Comment: understood. thanks for posting your answer. you should post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

I have researched this solution by installing the Papyrus font, and it works well (without any @font-face in any css file), but researching with several browsers on a Mac (running Lion) I found that although it worked well in Safari and Firefox, the Papyrus option doesn't show up in the text editor font dropdown in Chrome. I see others have had some Chrome issues in related areas, so I'm not sure if this is fixable in Chrome or not.

I added Papyrus=Papyrus in the two .js files, in the same relative position order, and added the fonts folder as described, with font file Papyrus.TTF (upper and lower case as shown).

In Safari and Firefox this results in Papyrus in the dropdown, and Papyrus font in the editor text, and on the website page, exactly as required.

But not in Chrome since the font can't be chosen.

Comment: I found a mistake I made - but it is helpful to have researched it. I had NOT got the Papyrus font in the same place in the two .js files - and clearly Chrome is sensitive to that and Safari / Firefox are not. I discovered that when I added the theme_advanced_fonts: preference into the head of the editing page, along with other tinyMCE init preferences (a duplication of the line in either of the .js files) and then Chrome worked. I realised that I had misplaced the Papyrus font in one of the .js files, and correcting that, and even after removing the init instruction, all browsers worked fine.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the @font-face would achieve - I guess it's nothing to do with the font list offered in the dropdown in the editor but more to do with the overall appearance of the editing dialog. I hope this is useful and not too confusing!