# How to add both custom font and google font family in tiny mce editor plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I am using wordpress tinymce editor plugin and have to add new custom font in existing font-family dropdown. How to add this?

I tried to add the custom font in the plugin but it shows only the custom font

[How to add a new font in tinymce editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499198/how-to-add-a-new-font-in-tinymce-editor)